# the following css doesn't work for second link

Tags: css, class, hyperlink

```
 a.nhl:link,a.nhl:visited{font-style:verdana;background: #fff; position: relative;     padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px; color: #666; font-size: 15px; 
font-weight:200; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 24px;-ms-word-wrap: break-word;  word-wrap: break-word;}
a.nhl:active{color:red;text-decoration:underline;}

a.nhl:hover{color:red;text-decoration:underline;}



a.nhls:link,a.nhls:visited {font-style:verdana;background: #fff; position: relative; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 5px; color: #666; font-size: 15px; 

font-weight: 200; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 24px;-ms-word-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;}
a.nhls:active{color:red;text-decoration:underline;}
a.nhls:hover{font:bold;color:red;text-decoration:underline;}



     <a class='nhls' href=\"index.php\"  > Home </a >  
    <a class='nhl'  href=\"index.php?title=sample\"> sample </a >
```

The above css doesn't work for the second link.  I am unable to find out what's wrong with class and link.

Thanks

Comment: pls Make fiddle of ur code its not readable !

Comment: Your code is working perfectly. http://jsfiddle.net/37g8avg7/

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your css: `font-style: verdana` is not valid (if you are trying to specify a font, you need `font-face`), `font: bold` should be `font-weight: bold`, and it could be rewritten to be much clearer and more compact. Try the following:

```
a.nhl:link,a.nhl:visited,a.nhls:link,a.nhls:visited { 
    font: 200 15px/24px Verdana;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: #666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
a.nhl:active, a.nhl:hover,a.nhls:active,a.nhls:hover {
    color:red;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a.nhls:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

According to the code you posted, both links will be underlined and red in the hover and active states, and the first link will be bold in the hover state. If you want the `text-decoration: underline` directive to take effect, you'll need to make sure that you've previously set `text-decoration: none` on links, as browsers frequently underline links by default.

What I did:

- combined a.nhl:link,a.nhl:visited and a.nhls:link,a.nhls:visited into a single declaration as they were identical;
- combined all the classes with `color: red` and `text-decoration: underline` in a single declaration;
- used the `font` shorthand to set font weight, size, line height, and font face;
- tidied up the formatting.

If you are having problems with your css, I advise you to use [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/) to check for errors in the code.